# what is referred to as a variable - its value or its identifier?

Tags: c#

I was reading an article in which it said:

"The variable referring to an instance of Value Type represents the starting address of the Value Type instance allocated on the stack."

Suppose I have a variable:

```
int age = 20;
```

We know `int` is a ValueType, so in the above line of code `age` is an instance of `Integer` ValueType ... but I'm unable to understand this above line written in the article .. which says - variable referring to an instance of Value Type represents the starting address of the ValueType instance allocated on stack. Does writer mean - `age` the variable identifier refers to the starting address of ValueType instance allocated on the stack or value 20 represents the starting address of the ValueType instance allocated on stack?

Can someone please help?

Comment: Seriously... this is an implementation detail. Thinking about things in terms of addresses is something you can entirely avoid with C# unless you're doing interop.

Comment: @Rehan Khan You have to be known about things like stack heap and memory allocation.. I would suggest you to read this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/76153/Six-important-NET-concepts-Stack-heap-value-types  and then try one more time to figure out what it the Value types.

Comment: @AndriiTsok Thanks for the useful advice and the link. I am sure I will check it out. I already know what is ValueType. My question is, in general when we say x is a variable of type integer and its value is 10, what are we referring variable to - variable identified x or variable value 10. ?

Comment: @RehanKhan in C# variables is representing or value or reference for the value... and it never represents itself. `x` it's somethings that you using to code. But in runtime it just a container with value/reference.

Comment: @AndriiTsok Please explain your answer little bit more? Because I am convinced with BoltClock's answer given below.

Comment: @AndriiTsok when you declare a variable in your program - that variable is allocated in memory - either on stack or heap. On runtime, it is accessed from either of those regions .. what do you mean by container? I mean when compiler sees that a variable of of type ValueType (int,float,long,short,byte,bool etc), it allocates it to `stack` region of your computer memory and then access it whenever it needs to and if this variable you declared is of type ReferenceType(class,object,interface,delegate,string), it allocates it immediately to `heap` region of your computer and then access it whenever

Comment: @AndriiTsok In the above given scenario, what do you mean by container on runtime?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally, a "variable" refers to the thing that holds a value, not the value itself. In this case, the variable is that which is known by its identifier `age`. Putting aside the topic of addresses and memory allocations, one could say:

> The `age` variable, which is of the `int` value type, is assigned a value of 20.

(The value may change at any other point in time during program execution, but in this particular assignment, it is 20.)